# Pandas - How to get information from the ExcelFile object

Tags: python, pandas, worksheet

I am trying to get a list of specific worksheet names from an Excel spreadsheet to allow me to extract each worksheet as a df, and perform the same task on each.
The worksheets are recognised by pandas when I run.
`df = pd.ExcelFile('reportsOut/SMART-TECH-321 GLOBAL CBO POSTSet Mapping 1.0 - MJK.xlsx')`
Getting the console output of the worksheets I am interested in, and ignoring the others.

```
AWC - POSTSETs  
EMR - POSTSETs  
GA - POSTSETs  
RSTL - POSTSETs  
SET - POSTSETs  
<pandas.io.excel._base.ExcelFile object at 0x00000223D5D1E550>
```

How could I capture the object as a list?
As df.sheet_names gives a full list, noting the names of the other worksheets may not always be the same:
['Intro - Cover Sheet', 'How to Use', 'Version History', 'AWC - POSTSETs', 'EMR - POSTSETs', 'GA - POSTSETs', 'RSTL - POSTSETs', 'SET - POSTSETs', 'Lookups']

Answer (score 1):

To target specific worksheets you can utilize the argument: '`sheet_name`'
for example sake, let's say you have report1 as the sheet you wish to access. You can write:

```
df = pd.ExcelFile('reportsOut/SMART-TECH-321 GLOBAL CBO POSTSet Mapping 1.0 - MJK.xlsx', sheet_name = 'report1')
```

you can proceed to select columns with '`usecols`'.

Comment: Thanks Keelan, although I am not trying to access sheets from specific sheet names I already know. I am trying to get the list of the sheet names that ExcelFile object is showing in the console. ExcelFile is doing a good job of ignoring those sheets in the spreadsheet that do not have tables of data.. If I could access that list, then I can apply the process to other spreadsheets where I don't know any of the  sheet names.

Comment: Hey @VC, my apologies for misunderstanding. I've had a little play around and believe you can extract sheet names with the following:

'import pandas as pd
FilePath = r'path.xlsx'
excel_Sheet_names = (pd.ExcelFile(FilePath)).sheet_names
print(excel_Sheet_names)'

I didn't realize this could be done so looks like I've learnt something too!

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that one. I will be able to use that for something. I am still trying to figure out why my initial command is only highlighting worksheets with only a table of information and ignoring worksheets with just random information.